# @Html.Raw not working when @Html.DisplayFor is

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

In a razor view showing some HTML content like this :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Content)
```

I want to output raw Html with :

```
@Html.Raw(model => model.Content)
```

Because otherwise html tags are displayed instead of being parsed.

But I get the error :

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public IHtmlString Raw(
    string value
)
```

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx), **Html.Raw** method accepts the string as parameter, not lambda expression.

Change `@Html.Raw(model => model.Content)` to `@Html.Raw(Model.Content)` and make sure the Content property is type of **string**.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to .net and don't know a thing... I don't understand why (model => model.Content) isn't returning a String when Model.Content is. Would you care briefly explaining?